# how to lock check items in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

the code is perfect, but how can i lock the check items (ONLY REQUIRED items) in listview?

```
        lvFees.Columns.Add("Fee", 120)
    lvFees.Columns.Add("Amount", 76)
    connect()
    rec.Open("select * from tablePayments where sem='" & cboSem.Text & "'", con, 3, 3)
    If rec.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do Until rec.EOF
            lvFees.Items.Add(rec("payname").Value)
            lvFees.Items(i).SubItems.Add(rec("amount").Value)
            If rec("paytype").Value = "REQUIRED" Then ' the paytype has two options, the "REQUIRED" and OPTIONAL.
                lvFees.Items(i).Checked = True
            End If
            rec.MoveNext()
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End If
    rec.Close()
    con.Close()
```

i want to lock the check of all REQUIRED item, while letting the user to check and uncheck the OPTIONAL items

Comment: Your code is not perfect.  You are vulnerable to sql injection.  Better use parameters on that query string.  And if that's DAO, you are better off using ado.net.

Comment: sorry, but the term perfect I'm referring is that, my code has no errors, it runs perfect but all i need is to lock the checked items, so that the user won't uncheck the REQUIRED items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are lower-level ways of accomplishing this, such as by inheriting the `ListView` class and overriding some of its behavior, but for a simpler approach, you could simply force the value in the `ItemChecked` event.  You could use the `Tag` property of each item in the list to keep track of its "locked" value.  For instance, if you loaded a `ListView` control with three items like this:

```
ListView1.Items.Add("Unlocked")
ListView1.Items.Add("Locked On").Tag = True
ListView1.Items(1).Checked = True
ListView1.Items.Add("Locked Off").Tag = False
```

And then put code like this in the `ItemChecked` event handler:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked
    If e.Item.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
        e.Item.Checked = DirectCast(e.Item.Tag, Boolean)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then that makes it so the check box of the first item can be altered by the user, but the other two items are locked in their respective states.

Comment: I need to make some research on how to use tag property, thanks sir.

Comment: You don't need to use the `Tag` property.  You could accomplish the same thing by having a way to look-up the value in the original data source or a `Dictionary` or something based on whichever item was clicked, but the `Tag` property is the most convenient thing for a simple example.